# How to call Custom Field in Wordpress Template

Tags: wordpress

I want to call custom field in single.php template to complete a short code and thus show a menu.

I places the below code but it is not working

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[custommenu menu=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘tabmenu’, true); ?>]?>")
```

Please help

Here's my template file

I saved this as single-default.php and calling it category wise from single.php file

> 

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="content">



        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>



<div class="tab-menu"><?php echo do_shortcode("[custommenu menu='".get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘tabmenu’, true)."']"); ?>
</div>






            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php if(get_option('resizable_integrate_singletop_enable') == 'on') echo (get_option('resizable_integration_single_top')); ?>      
                <?php the_content(''); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'themejunkie' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                <?php if(get_option('resizable_integrate_singlebottom_enable') == 'on') echo (get_option('resizable_integration_single_bottom')); ?>                        
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php printf(the_tags(__('<div class="entry-tags"><span>Tags:</span>&nbsp;','themejunkie'),', ','</div>')); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link('('.__('Edit', 'themejunkie').')', '<span class="entry-edit">', '</span>'); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

        <div class="clear"></div>


        <div class="entry-bottom">



                          <div class="clear"></div>

        </div><!-- .entry-bottom -->



    </div><!-- #content -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the inner echo in the shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[custommenu menu='".get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘tabmenu’, true)."']"); ?>
```

Comment: This works but he issue is that. I have two menus say MENU0 MENU1. But this code shows Menu0 on every post either I have MENU0 or MENU1 in tabmenu custom field

Comment: are you echoing that inside each iteration your post loop? its hard to say without seeing the template but thats what it sounds like to me. post your template and ill take a look

Comment: hello andrew, thanks for your followups, I have posted teh template file in the question please check and save me